# How to point Tomcat8 to an older version of Java so that Geoserver can run correctly

Tags: java, environment-variables, tomcat8, geoserver

I have installed Tomcat8 in Ubuntu 18.04 and then installed Geoserver into the webapp directory which worked great. I made sure that I had Java 8 installed as Geoserver does not run on newer versions of Java. However, recently I installed a newer version of java for other programs to run properly, since then I can't get Geoserver to work. When I looked at the Tomcat8 web manager I noticed it was pointing to the new version of Java:

[image]

I then tried changing the version of Java being used by changing the $JAVA_HOME and $JRE_HOME to:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"
export PATH=$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH

source /etc/profile

echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

This made no difference, I also tried:

```
update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

And I selected option 2. This did not work either. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Also, ideally I just want to change the default Java for Tomcat8 to Java 8 and keep the newer version as default elsewhere.

Comment: You would need to provide the absolute path to every Java binary you use to start the tomcat server

Comment: You don't have JDK 8 installation?